# SQL Server 2019 standard get error when create index on temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have some code try to create a temp table on SQL Server with the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #POM_read_expr_scratch2 ( auid VARCHAR(15) collate Latin1_General_BIN, aint_val INT ) ;
SELECT MAX(partition_number) FROM sys.partitions WHERE object_id = object_id( '#POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2' ) HAVING MAX(partition_number) > 1;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX re_scratch_index ON #POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2 ( auid )   ;
COMMIT;
```

This code work with SQL Server 2016 Developer version. however when run with 2019 Standard version (DBMS VERSION:: 15.0.2000.5 RTM Standard Edition (64-bit)) we get following error:

> DBC error. SQLSTATE: 42000 Native error: 1088 Message:
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot find the object
> "#POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2" because it does not exist or you do not have
> permissions. Approx SQL was "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX re_scratch_index ON
> #POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2 ( auid ) "
>
> Error creating index re_scratch_index on table
> #POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2.
> *** EIM_check_error: code 1088, dbmsg='[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot find the object "#POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2"
> because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'

We check the documentation, but didn't see any restriction of creating index on temp table. Can anyone explain why could this happens?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f036a86fe4edfc5cc60f3f3a3026978)

Comment: Clearly your 2016 Developer Edition and 2019 Standard Edition installations are configured differently. Try reproducing it in a new install in a VM/lab environment.

Comment: I can't replicate either, 
As you've provided a snippet of the code, as you should.
I can only guess you might have a `DROP TABLE` in the lines between `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` in your code.

Comment: Do note that `#POM_read_expr_scratch2` is not the same thing as `#POM_READ_EXPR_SCRATCH2`, if you have happened to install your server with a case-sensitive default collation, so that's another possible source of problems.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(partition_number) FROM sys.partitions` should be `tempdb.sys.partitions`

Comment: Jeroen Mostert
I think you may right. Yes from the log i notice the SQL are slight different (table name is upper case) which could be the reason. As we have two MSSQL, it could be MSSQL standard 2019 which is case senstive but MSSQL 2016 is not sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think query you want is below:

```
CREATE TABLE #POM_read_expr_scratch2 (
  auid VARCHAR(15) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN INDEX re_scratch_index CLUSTERED
 ,aint_val INT
);
```

Comment: The index defined here is not unique, and for whatever reason, specifying `UNIQUE` in an inline column index definition doesn't work. The column could be defined as a primary key, though that's not exactly the same thing. To achieve the same thing inline you need `CREATE TABLE(..., INDEX re_scratch_index UNIQUE CLUSTERED (auid))`. That said, there are good reasons for not having the index created inline, of course, so this doesn't necessarily answer the question.